# Updating a date row and time row within MySQL with php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm getting the following error when I try to update a date and a time row within my table:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'date = '7890-06-06' time = '12:34:00' ' at line 3

Not entirely sure why I'm getting this as I'm using '' in the sql code and the format in the tables is all correct.

PHP code:

```
<?php

    include 'database_conn.php';

    if(!$conn)
    {
        echo "Error connecting to database";
    }

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
    {
        echo "<p>Connection failed:".mysqli_connect_error()."</p>\n";
    }

    $eventid = isset($_GET['eId']) ? $_GET['eId'] : NULL; 
    $title = isset($_REQUEST['titleField']) ? $_REQUEST['titleField'] : '';
    $time = isset($_REQUEST['timeField']) ? $_REQUEST['timeField'] : '';
    $date = isset($_REQUEST['dateField']) ? $_REQUEST['dateField'] : '';
    $location = isset($_REQUEST['locationField']) ? $_REQUEST['locationField'] : '';
    $description = isset($_REQUEST['descriptionField']) ? $_REQUEST['descriptionField'] : '';

    //echo "Event: $eventid";
    //echo "User: $uid";
    //echo "Comment: $comment";
    echo "$date";
    echo "$time";       

    $sql = "UPDATE Events
            SET name = '$title'                        
                date = '$date'
                time = '$time'
                location = '$location'
                description = '$description'

            WHERE eventid = '$eventid'
            ";

    $results = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)
         or die(mysqli_error($conn));

    if($results)
    {
        echo "Event successfully edited";
    }

    mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

Not sure the best way to represent the table, but here it is:

```
#   Name    Type
1   eventid int(11)
2   name    varchar(255)
3   date    date
4   time    time
5   location    varchar(255)
6   description varchar(1000)
```

Comment: u are missing colons after `SET` values, and u are missing semicolon in here `$results = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)`

Comment: $sql = "UPDATE Events SET name = '$title', date = '$date', time = '$time', location = '$location', description = '$description' WHERE eventid = '$eventid'";

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 0):

you should add comma separations',' between sets statements:

```
   $sql = "UPDATE Events
                SET name = '$title',                        
                    date = '$date',
                    time = '$time',
                    location = '$location',
                    description = '$description'

                WHERE eventid = '$eventid'
                ";
```